# Why does an inner class instance remian in the memory even if the outer class object is destroyed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inner-classes, local-class

Please consider following two classes:

**a.) Student**

```
package datatypes;

public class Student {

    private String name ;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    class Address{
        String city;
        String state;

        Address(String city , String state){
            this.city = city;
            this.state = state;
        }

        String getAddress(){
            return city + state;
        }

    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

**b.) StudentDemo**

```
package datatypes;

import datatypes.Student.Address;

public class StudentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student obj = new Student("Yati");
        Address adr = obj.new Address("YNR" , "HARYANA");

        System.out.println(obj.getName());
        System.out.println(adr.getAddress());

        obj=null;

        //System.out.println(obj.getName());
        System.out.println(adr.getAddress()); //Line 16

    }
}
```

According to [oracle java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> For creating an instance of the inner class first we have to create an instance of the enclosing class and later we can create the instances of the inner class.

Like other members (instance variables and instance methods) inner class is also a member of the instance of the outer class. In **line no 16** of StudentDemo.java I am still able to print the value of the address even if the object which was responsible for the creation of **Address** object **DOES NOT** exist in the memory.

My question is: why does the Address object remains in the memory and doesn't get destroyed automatically once the **obj** is set to null?

Output:

```
Yati
YNRHARYANA
YNRHARYANA
```

Comment: ... because the parent object isn't destroyed.

Comment: Setting a field to `null` just sets that field to `null`, nothing else magically happens.

Comment: Hint: your test run output ... is **text**. So dont create a screenshot and link to that; but put in the **text** into your question. And: we use **markup** language; no point in using `<br>` tags. In other words: read all that helpful information around that preview editor/window when writing your question. That stuff is there for reason. Still, funny question .. p1 from my end!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting a reference to **null** does not mean that the garbage collector immediately collects the corresponding object from memory!

And beyond that: the GC can't even collect your object; because `adr` still has a reference to the "inner object"; and that one has a reference to its outer owner!

So, even when you would add a `System.gc()` call after doing `obj = null` ... that object can **not** be collected. (and just for the record: calling `gc()` is just a "hint" to the JVM to run the garbage collector; there are no guarantees that anything happens)

Long story short: **of course** things have to work this way. Your code holds a reference to an *inner* object; and while that reference is there, that object must exist. And while that *inner* object must exist; so must its *outer* parent. In other words: the whole system **relies** on the fact that the life time of inner/outer objects **are** tightly coupled!

And given your last comment - how is the runtime supposed to know that this *inner* object could live with its *outer* parent being null?! You might call a method on *inner* that actually uses *outer.this*; and then what, NullPointerException?!

So the real answer might be to understand that you asking a purely theoretical questions. In the "real" world you would simply not do that. In the real world, you would not hand out references to inner objects; not caring about their outer parent. Similar to Domain Driven Design - there an **aggregation** of objects is also *only* accepted via the *root* object of the aggregation (see [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) for example). That is of course not the same as objects within the JVM; but as said: an example that you simply do things differently for **conceptual** reasons.

Comment: Isn't `System.gc()` advisory?

Comment: @Bathsheba It is. But I have done many experiments where it surprisingly did exactly what I was looking for: to immediately "clear" things that I null'ed before that call. But I will clarify my answer.

Comment: "In other words: the whole system relies on the fact that the life time of inner/outer objects are tightly coupled!" I agree with this. 
But I am still wandering what would be the significance of an inner class object in an application when the enclosing class object is no longer needed ( from programming point of view , setting reference to null ). It would be an overhead in terms of memory. isn't it?

Comment: what if the anonymous inner class was created inside a method would it still exist in memory even after method returns? the scope of the anonymous class is only within the method right ?

Comment: That depends what exactly you do. Keep in mind: garbage collection works by first identifying all objects that aren't alive. This means: as long as an object can *somehow* be reached from another alive object, it can't be collected. From that point of view, it doesn't matter where/how an object is created. It only matters if there are references somewhere that are pointing to that object. Beyond that: normally you should ask a new question for such things, but I decided to shortcut and answer right here. Feel free to upvote here or there if my answer is helpful for you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that a reference to your inner class is still in use, all your inner and outer class shenanigans are red herrings.

The fact remains that writing

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f = null;
```

for any class `Foo`, will merely *cause* the created instance of `Foo` to be *scheduled* for garbage collection. The object will not necessarily be destroyed immediately.

Comment: I thought so, too. But actually, that is not true. He has **two** references; and the second one pulls in the "outer", too!

Comment: I just spotted that too. I think we both essentially have the same answer, so the only rational recourse is to upvote yours.

Comment: Anyways; people upvote way to rarely. So, lets see what I can do about that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> if the object which was responsible for the creation of Address object DOES NOT exist in the memory

Of course it does: it's referenced from `adr`, and `adr` is accessible, so it can't be garbage-collected. Even if it wasn't referenced, it wouldn't necessarily be collected immediately.

Comment: "wouldn't be" -> "wouldn't necessarily be"

Comment: @Bathsheba Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

An object is eligible for destruction when there is no more reference to it or there is no more reference to any object in the graph of reference it participates in. Two simple cases:

`(o)` a single "lost" object

`(o1) <- (o2)` two "lost "objects"

In the second case, if you have a reference on `(o1)` then `(o1)` is not lost but `(o2)` is.

An inner object has a reference to its enclosing outer object, and as you have a reference to the inner object, then there exists a "living" reference to its outer object. You have something like:

`(outer <- (inner) <-)----some reference`